# how to prevent the browser from opening new sessions for images loaded by javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, visitor-statistic

I have designed a system to get some user data(screen resolution and etc) by javascript.
In HTML files, by javascript, screen resolutions will be send to server via get parameters of a url(an image).
the problem is that when the image is requested from server, a new session instance will be created, while I expect that the session for getting the image would be the same as the session of the parent page.
please, if you have any idea how could I resolve this problem.
thank alot.

the codes I am using are as follows:

I have put a javascript in all of my web pages to get screen resolution. Here is the javascript code:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 document.getElementById("mypictureid").src="http://www.mywebsite.com/getresolutionpic.php?w="+screen.width+"&h="+screen.height;
</script>
```

and the html of the pages includes:

```
<img id="mypictureid" src="http://mywebsite.com/otherimage.gif"
```

and the following php code will be executed with each page loading to store user data in $_SESSION.

```
$some_name = session_name("generalvisit");
session_start();
$_SESSION['entertime']=new DateTime();
```

and to track the user a userid is created by a mysql database and stores in $_SESSION['userid']

```
if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['userid'])) $_SESSION['userid']=getNewUserID();
```

now, when the  `getresolutionpic.php` is triggered by javascript,  store screen resolution of that user stores in the `$_SESSION` variable of the same user. In `getresolutionpic.php` we have:

```
$some_name = session_name("generalvisit");
session_start();
if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    $_SESSION['userid']=getNewUserID();
    $_SESSION['entertime']=new DateTime();
}
$_SESSION['width']=$_GET['w'];
$_SESSION['height']=$_GET['h'];
```

The problem is that when getresolutionpic.php is called, `$_SESSION['userid']` is empty and a new userid will be created while the user is not actually new.

Do you have any idea where it goes wrong?

Comment: I know `www.mywebsite.com` is not your actual website, but for the image example url you use `mywebsite.com` which is a different host and may result in a new session, unless you've configured the cookie to be valid for all subdomains.

Comment: as Barmar recommended, I changed javascript so that it loads after the page. i.e. putting the script within window.onload but unfortunately, it did not resolve my problem

Comment: @Prinzhorn, all urls have www in them, both the image url and the main page

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in both if statements, is that your actual code? `if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['userid'])`

Comment: @Prinzhorn, no it is not the actual one, the actual one is corret. thanks

Comment: Can you check with your favourite browser's debugger/developer tools that the session cookie is correctly sent in both requests (and that it's the same)?

Comment: how can I check that?